# how to create a folder with user name or email?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

[I've tried to make a folder whenever someone registered into my system but i don't know how to create it with the name of user name or user email any help?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYnEp.png)

Comment: i have attached a screenshot of my code as well

Comment: Would you mind adding some details to your query? Please have a look at this guide to understand how to ask a good question : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

This should be what you're looking for

```
string directoryPath = Server.MapPath(string.Format("~/{0}/", txtFolderName.Text.Trim()));
    if (!Directory.Exists(directoryPath))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryPath);
    }
```